# What is the underlying technology in RPA that enables features/capabilities like the recorder, executing functions, etc

Tags: .net, automation, rpa, uipath, blueprism

Let me start by apologizing if this is not the appropriate place for my question.

I am working on a project where I am trying to highlight the capabilities of RPA. Rather than just on the surface use cases and how RPA can revolutionize automation I am trying to understand the underlying technology that RPA is built from. (I have zero coding or computer science experience)

I have identified the following key features that enable RPA to be a true innovation and not just screen scraping.

- **Scraping** data even when the application is hidden
- Recognizing controls
- Working off images when in VMs like Citirix
- Record Functionality
- Unattended Robots
- Market place for new features

What I am hoping to understand is how ".Net" or "VB" enables this **scraping** functionality and why RPA companies decide to develop their tools in ".Net" vs another langauge. Im also trying to understand how the recorder works. It seems like it needs to be object orient to record a workflow however I don't understand what technology allows the recorder function to exist. I am also trying to understand what technology allows for unattended robots. What tech creates the ability to tigger the workflow. Lastely in regards to the market place it seems like UiPath is using "NuGet". Why would this be the right approach?

I understand this is a bit of an odd request. I am just trying to learn as much as possible. I am also open to a call if anyone is open to it.

Thank you in advance.

Ryan

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ not scrapping

Comment: Not really sure how to answer on this. What is your aim?

Comment: Hi @kwoxer - I am looking to just learn and get the perspective of someone that understands RPAs core software. I am putting together a PowerPoint to talk about how RPA is growing and the reason for its growth is due to its features. When I look at the features they are great however I don't know understand how the features were built. For example, I found that UiPath uses XML for its selectors rather than XPath or CSS. Why is that a good thing?

Comment: CSS is only for selecting the web. But usually automation tools can also interact with any installed application. So there is a need for an CSS alternative. And there it can be XPATH, XML, Json or whatever. This is kind of the developers pick. There is readability versus small files. So this depends heavily on what you more rely on.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask this in the Software Engineering forum.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

RPA tools evolved from Test Automation tools like LoadRunner that became popular in the 1990's and Selenium more recently. The Microsoft Office VBA macro recorder that appeared around 2000 is also an ancestor. Then there is workflow (and business process) automation - UiPath RPA, for instance, uses Microsoft Windows Workflow Foundation. All these bits along with OCR and newer tricks are going into RPA.